# If inputType is number soft keyboard covers edittext field

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad, android-inputtype

It is working fine for default inputType but for number, screen doesn't get resized.
I am using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest file for activity.
I have 'Mail ID' and 'Mobile No' fields in the bottom of the form.like this

[image]

It works fine for Mail ID..

[image]

But for Mobile No which is number field..

[image]

Here is part of my xml file... mobile no is editTest field with inputType number in last.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white_smoke"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/FormItemStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextFormLabel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Name*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_f_name"
                    style="@style/EditTextBgStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords|textNoSuggestions" />
            </LinearLayout>
.
.
.
.
other view 
           .
              .

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/FormItemStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/check_adds_same_as_per"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Same as Permanent Address" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/TextFormLabel"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Communication Address*" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_commun_adds"
                        style="@style/EditTextBgStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2.5"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:maxLines="4"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/FormItemStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextFormLabel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mail ID" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_mail_id"
                    style="@style/EditTextBgStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/FormItemStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextFormLabel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mobile No*" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_mobile_no"
                    style="@style/EditTextBgStyle"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="10" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/master_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustSpan"

Comment: Do you mean "adjustPan" right ?  I have tried that also ..it doesn't works.

Comment: try to put your layout with scrollview

Comment: It is in scrollview only.

Comment: do you have fillviewport = true for scrollView?

Comment: I haven't set that attribute ..should i set it false ?

Comment: tried  fillviewport  true and false but no luck..

Comment: This is weird then... can you post your xml? so we can try to run it on our devices?

Comment: I have edited the question with part of my xml file..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
try to use  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in `Manifest.xml`

Comment: @HarryMad then `adjustUnspecified` ?

Comment: android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to the root view?

Comment: @HarryMad can you show your xml file? so it will be easier to help